# Django rest-framework does not store authenticated user between calls

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

For the project I'm currently working on, I decided to write a custom authentication model. I'm using both the rest-framework and all-access. The local authentication is not implemented yet (it is, but in a different version, so no issue there).

The User model registers properly and OAuth authentication works. Users get logged alright.

When working with views, authentication works properly if I use django's View as base class. Not so much if I use rest-framework's APIView.

In my ProfileView (LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL redirects here) I receice a rest_framework.request.Request instance, which is OK by me. The problem is:

request.user is an instance of AnonymousUser (even after login)

I would guess the problem lies with my implementation, but then:

request._request.user is an authenticated user

(Note that request._request is the original django request)

I tend to think this is a rest-framework bug, but maybe one of you knows of a workaround?

**Edit**
Just to note that the login is made in a non-APIView class, but instead in a class that inherits from View. That's probably the reason the User instance is not passed to the APIView instance.

Comment: provide some code, what you have done?

Comment: Well, in this case I didn't think it would be necessary because, well, it works! In my get_or_create_user() method I have this: return User.objects.create_user(**kwargs) which does return a User instance (kwargs is a standard dictionary with all the fields). The problem is not authenticating, the problem is that the rest-framework seems to be creating its own AnonymousUser instance, instead of using the one provided by django natively.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` in your `settings.py`. Else DRF will default to `None` as `request.auth` and `AnonymousUser` as `request.user`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Once you set that and the user is logged in, ensure that the `session_id` is available in the request headers. Browsers typically store the session information and pass it in the headers of all requests.

If you are using a non-browser client (Eg. a mobile app), you will need to set the session id manually in the header.

Also since you mentioned you use `oauth` to sign-in the user, for `oauth2` you need to specify the oauth2 authorization header instead of the session id.

```
"Authorization: Bearer <your-access-token>"
```

Refer to Authenticating in [Django Rest Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication.html#oauthauthentication)

Comment: I'm not using rest-framework's authentication model. I have defined my own backend and user model. What should I put there, then?

Comment: Btw, I'm using session authentication.

Comment: You will need to implement your custom authetication by subclassing Baseauthentication and provide that method in the settings.py. Eg http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication.html#custom-authentication